# Behavior of electron in free state and bound state

Tags: particle-physics, waves, experimental-physics, wave-particle-duality

Why does a free state electron totally behave like a particle?
also what will be the behavior of electrons in bound state?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does a free state electron totally behave like a particle?

Physics is the observation and measurement of nature, and its theories develop from appropriate mathematical equations  in order for the solutions to model these measurements, and , very important, to be predictive of new measurements. To succeed in finding the proper solutions, extra axioms must be imposed on the solutions of the differential equations so that the model fits the data and observations.

The location of particles is given as a probability of being measured at an (x,y,z,t) by the $Ψ^*Ψ$  where Ψ is the wave
function solution for the specific boundary conditions and system. This is part of the [postulates](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) (extra axioms) of quantum mechanics.

That a free electron leaves footprints of a particle ,for example points in screens and trajectories in bubble chambers, is an observable fact that has to be modeled by the theory.

At the moment, the quantum field theory we have,  which is very successful in predictions, models particles as plane waves. Plane wave cannot predict the location of point particles as the probability is spread all over space, so they cannot model a free electron. They are modeled using the plane wave wave functions with a spread, consistent with the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, by [wave packets.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html) This is not necessary for calculations of interactions of electrons with other particles as the QFT is predictive with point particles in the [Feynman diagrams.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html)

> also what will be the behavior of electrons in bound state?

In a bound state the probability of measuring the electron at an (x,y,z,t) is given by the wavefunction solution of the atom containing it, and [is seen](https://www.nature.com/articles/498009d) in the [orbitals](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) .